# Not able to figure out how to wait until forEach loop iterates completely and use that result

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to cloud functions (node js with typescript). I am using it to fetch data from Firebase database( as the code below). But Not able to figure out how to wait until forEach loop iterates completely and use that result.

```
  const reference = admin.database().ref('/books')
  var path_key:string
  var total_count:number = 0
  reference .forEach(function (snapshot) {
        path_key= snapshot(key).val()
         ref_users_advance_bookings.child(path_key) 
         .once('value').then((snapshot2)=>{

         if(condidtion met){
          return response.send("failed")
          }
          else{
           total_count++ 
           }
         )}

     return true 
    }) 
     // i want to use total_count value here
     return response.send("count :"+total_count) // but every time I gets 0, as it get executed before forEach has ended
   )}
```

Comment: What is `ref`? Please check [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you're trying to wait for a number of items to load from the database. For that you'll want to use `Promise.all()`, in something like:

```
var promises = [];
ref.forEach(function (snapshot) {
    path_key= snapshot(key).val()
    promises.push(ref_users_advance_bookings.child(path_key).once('value'));
});

Promise.all(promises).then(function(snapshots) {
    var failed = false;
    snapshot.forEach(function(snapshot2) {
        if(condition met){
            failed = true;
        }
        else {
            total_count++;
        }
    )}
    if (failed) {
        return response.status(500).send("ERROR");
    }
    else {
        return response.send("count :"+total_count);
    }
});
```